# Case statement - not working

Tags: t-sql

I have the following case statement:

```
, ADMIT_DATE_TIME                       = CASE
    WHEN PE.HSP_ACCOUNT_ID IS NOT NULL  THEN CASE 
        WHEN HA.ACCT_BASECLS_HA_C = 1 THEN A3.IP_ADMIT_DATE_TIME 
        ELSE HA.ADM_DATE_TIME 
      END
    ELSE PE.EFFECTIVE_DATE_DT 
  END   /* Export in YYYYMMDD HH:MM format  FYI - No time component in EFFECTIVE_DATE_DT */
```

What I am expecting is that when the field PE.HSP_ACCOUNT_ID IS NOT NULL then I should see PE.EFFECTIVE_DATE_DT. However this is not happening.  PE.EFFECTIVE_DATE_DT does have a value however the result I am seeing is NULL.

Am I missing something? 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: you are telling 'when  PE.HSP_ACCOUNT_ID IS NOT NUL' show PE.EFFECTIVE_DATE_DT. So, the first validation is wrong. Try  WHEN PE.HSP_ACCOUNT_ID IS NULL  THEN

Comment: I do not get an error, the issue is I am getting a NULL value when expecting to see the value for PE.Effective_Date_DT (this i know is not null)

Comment: See the answer i post, i think thats the problem.

Comment: @Silspar24, sample data and desired results will help people help you find an answer because I think people are having some problems understanding what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Acording to what you write the statement should be:

```
, ADMIT_DATE_TIME                       = CASE
    WHEN PE.HSP_ACCOUNT_ID IS NULL  THEN CASE 
        WHEN HA.ACCT_BASECLS_HA_C = 1 THEN A3.IP_ADMIT_DATE_TIME 
        ELSE HA.ADM_DATE_TIME 
      END
    ELSE PE.EFFECTIVE_DATE_DT 
  END   /* Export in YYYYMMDD HH:MM format  FYI - No time component in EFFECTIVE_DATE_DT */
```

when PE.HSP_ACCOUNT_ID is not null shows PE.EFFECTIVE_DATE_DT

Now the statement is going into the next case, so what it shows to you is

```
A3.IP_ADMIT_DATE_TIME OR HA.ADM_DATE_TIME
```

that i think is null.

Comment: Close.  This gives me the opposite.  I need to combine them so there are no NULL values.

Comment: Ok so upon further investigation... 
When PE.HSP_ACCOUNT_ID IS NOT NULL, I do want it to so the A3.IP_ADMIT_DATE_TIME OR HA.ADM_DATE_TIME and 9 out of 10 time this will be populated. But there are a handful of times when it is null. when it is null then I need to use PE.EFFECTIVE_DATE_DT

Comment: Can you add to the question some data for example.

Comment: I figured out what the issue was.  my Case statement issue, there were records that met criteria I did not consider and once I gathered the data to post on here i saw it.